# Saving the output of a python executable that launches a cmd-like window to a txt file

Tags: windows, command-line, python, cmd.exe, logging

I have a python executable file. When launched, it endlessly displays system logs on a cmd-like window. I cannot write any commands nor do I have access to the source code. Would it be possible to capture everything that this .exe displays to the screen and save into a txt file?

Comment: Redirect the output to a file.

Comment: @Toto I'm unable to write any commands. Is there a way to do that externally without any commands?

Comment: Instead of launching the executable, launch `executable > file.log`. If you need to see the output on the screen *and* in a file, google for `tee for windows`. No way to capture the output once the executable has started without redirection.